# Bank note recognition with neural network, must I crop the images for the dataset

Tags: python, image-processing

I am a blind guy and am busy creating a app to recognise South African and Namibian currency(bank notes).

I had my family take pictures of the bank notes that I can put into my dataset.  The bank note on a white paper.  Now to prepare my dataset with features and labels is it better to crop the bank note from the picture and save it as a image and use the cropped images in the data set or can I use the original picture that the bank note is on the white back ground?

For I was thinking of cropping the test image so only the bank note is vissable and so trying to get a higher accuracy or is this not correct with a cnn?  Also is it better to keep the colors for each bank note have a different color, and not grey scaling?
I used the neural network from Sendex for a starting point and used only 2 images in each and used data orgmentation to get more images, but the classification is not working correctly.  I Think maybe I have to little images in my database also, 100 of each.

Comment: i dont think a neural net is the right solution to this problem, i suspect it will be very easy to trick  ... you probably should use cropped images however

Comment: Thank you for your response.  If a neural network is not the way to go what will be the best solution to use?

Comment: I mean its worth a shot and it can probably give you a good idea(ie it looks real and is of denomination X) ... but it would fall for nearly any counterfeit bill i suspect  ... i dont think there is a camera solution (maybe with backlighting you can identify some of the security features... but im sure it would still be beatable)  ... further you will almost certainly have to figure out how to crop the images without user input (ie find the borders with something like opencv) because you will also have to crop the input picture

Comment: Thanks.  Yes at this stage was not thinking of authentication of notes but only to be able to find out what bank notes I have.  For even sighted people can not also always see if they have real money.  I stay alone and not always sure what bank notes I have for even though the notes have marks on the side to feel, when the notes is used it is not always possable to feel it.  So it is more just to give me a idea of what notes should they be authentic that I have.

Comment: Hi Hendrik, welcome to the forum! I don't have a lot of experience with NN's but I think they should do just fine for what you're trying to do. Here is a basic example of using tensorFlow for categorisation of images: https://github.com/UnnamedMoose/learningTensorFlow/tree/master/tutorial4_mnist. I think you'll definitely need to first condition the pixels from every image for feeding the NN (rotate, crop, ensure the same size). i know someone who might have some tools for it, I'll ask them.

Comment: If you can crop reliably, opt for cropping. As for greyscale vs leaving all colours there, greyscale can make the model a lot simpler, and the model can still pull off good classification in many tasks without the colour context. So, try both approaches, greyscaling if that works, if not, go for colour.

Comment: Thank you will try both with color and not.  Will check out the link

Comment: Hi, Well searching on google and see that opencv cropping.  Found one but it crops my image into 52 jpg images.  Guess it has something to do with a bank note have different areas on it with writing, lines, animal heads and so on.  Any ideas on how to to crop the full bank note and not crop it into all those smaller images? Here is the code I found and tested

Comment: import cv2 
image = cv2.imread("10.1.jpg")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 250)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
idx = 0
for c in cnts:
 x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
 if w>50 and h>50:
  idx+=1
  new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
  cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
cv2.imshow("im",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: I agree if you are simply trying to recognise the denomination ANN should probably work fine